# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LoginApp/displayForm.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'java4s'

Tags: spring-mvc

I am facing this error No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LoginApp/displayForm.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'java4s'

Earlier the page was redirecting but now it is not redirecting.

My code is as follows

**Java4sController.java**

```
package java4s;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
//import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
//import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import java.sql.*;
//import org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool;

//import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;


@Controller
public class Java4sController {    
    HttpSession session;
    String uname="",pass="";
    Statement stmt;
    Connection conn;

    @RequestMapping(value="displayForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld(UserDetails ud,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "loginPage";            
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginCheck(@Valid UserDetails userDetails, BindingResult result, ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In the login page");
        String username=userDetails.getUser();  
        String password=userDetails.getPassword();
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "loginPage";
        } 
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.
                 getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:C:/Users/aaggarwal/test", "sa", "");
            // add application code here
            if(conn!=null) {
                System.out.println("No connection");
            }
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            String sql="Select * FROM table1 WHERE username='"+username+"' AND password='"+password+"' ";
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                uname=rs.getString("username");
                pass=rs.getString("password");
                if (result.hasErrors()) {
                    return "loginPage";
                } else if(username.equals(uname)&&password.equals(pass)) {
                    //session.invalidate();
                    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
                    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
                    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
                    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
                    session = request.getSession(); // create session
                    session.setAttribute("username", username);
                    session.setAttribute("password", password);
                    //String str1=(String)session.getAttribute(username);

                    model.addAttribute("lfobj", userDetails);
                    //model.addAttribute(str1);
                    conn.close();
                    return "success";
                } else {
                    conn.close();
                    return "loginPage";
                }
            } 
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                conn.close();
            } catch(SQLException se){
            }// do nothing
            try{
            if(conn!=null)
              conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        return "abcd";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="logoutform", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld1(UserDetails ud,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("\nabcdef\n");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
        String username=ud.getUser();  
       // String password=ud.getPassword();

        HttpSession session1;
        session1=request.getSession(false);
        System.out.println("Session :"+session1.getAttribute("username"));
        if(session1!=null) {
            //session1.removeAttribute(username);
            session1.invalidate();
            Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                cookie.setValue(null);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
            System.out.println("invalidating session");
            //session1.invalidate();
        }
        return "logoutsuccess";            
    }
}
```

**java4s-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="java4s" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="props" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>java4s</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>java4s</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Change to `@RequestMapping(value="displayForm.html"`

Comment: I tried this there are other errors now like UserDetails cannot be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [`/LoginApp/displayForm.html`]** means no mapping for displayForm.html.

Because in **controller** you have given

```
@RequestMapping(value="displayForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Change that to

```
 @RequestMapping(value="displayForm.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Or in **web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>java4s</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @Archit Aggarwal ok what is UserDetails(is it from Spring Security or your bean class) and show the error

Comment: I resolved the error without making any changes in the code earlier also the same thing happened sometimes the code is working and sometime it is not working. It is working fine now without even changing displayform to displayform.html can you help me with it.

Comment: Ya i can help..what is the actual issue then?

Comment: The issue is sometimes the code works and sometimes the code does not work.

Comment: No it will not..it has to work same always..what error it will throw??

Comment: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LoginApp/displayForm.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'java4s'

Comment: Is it still giving??

Comment: No archit it will not give like that..atleast if it was front end code i would have convenienced but for backend code...

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/q/39073144/5633475?sem=2  @Prasanna Kumar