# Spring MVC loads blank webpage, but '/' is configured to load homepage. Setup done using no xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to build a Spring MVC application, using no XML. To load the application I am using a tomcat server. I want the homepage "home.html" to load, when I go to http://localhost:8080/.

I have followed many other spring mvc helloworld tutorials, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The webpage that loads, when I run the application is completely blank. When I inspect the html, it has an empty body. Any help is much appreciated.

Initialization class

```
  public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[]{"/"};
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[] {ApplicationConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[]{WebMvcConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
            CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
            characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

            DelegatingFilterProxy securityFilterChain = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");

            return new Filter[] {characterEncodingFilter, securityFilterChain};
        }

        @Override
        protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
            registration.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
            registration.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "default");
        }
    }
```

MVC configuration

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SOURCE = "/WEB-INF/i18n/messages";
    private static final String VIEWS = "/WEB-INF/views/";

    private static final String RESOURCES_LOCATION = "/resources/";
    private static final String RESOURCES_HANDLER = RESOURCES_LOCATION + "**";

    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
        return requestMappingHandlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(MESSAGE_SOURCE);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix(VIEWS);
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect()); //TODO no using Spring security
        templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(RESOURCES_HANDLER).addResourceLocations(RESOURCES_LOCATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    /**
     * Handles favicon.ico requests assuring no <code>404 Not Found</code> error is returned.
     */
    @Controller
    static class FaviconController {
        @RequestMapping("favicon.ico")
        String favicon() {
            return "forward:/resources/images/favicon.ico";
        }
    }
}
```

Home controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Here is what my views look like

[image: Here is what my views look like]

Comment: What is the content of home.html?....and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073144/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-loginapp-in-dispatcherservlet-wit/39075538#39075538) might help..

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. It was a problem with my maven artifact id and group id. I don't know what happened, but renaming those id's fixed the problem.