# Controller not functioning correctly Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I can load the jsp desired but the controller does not work with the jsp.  Also, for some reason if I place the jsp in the folder configuration that corresponds like the the web.xml/servletConfig files are mapped, then it wont let me access the jsp.  But if I place the jsp file in the webapp folder I am able to access it.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>projectHub</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/projectHub-servletConfig.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>projectHub</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

projectHub-servletConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.projectHub.controllers"></context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

Controller

```
package com.projectHub.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ProjectHubController {

    //http://localhost:8080/projectHub/homepage.html
    @RequestMapping(value="/homepage")
    public String getHomepage(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("titleHomepage", "ProjectHub");

        return "homepage";
    }

}
```

homepage.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>ProjectHub Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>${titleHomepage}</h1>
    <p>WTF</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Folder Structure image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z90r3.jpg

Comment: where is your homePage.jsp resides?? and show your directory structure

Comment: added image link for directory structure

Answer (score 0):

According to your configuration

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Your jsp's should reside in **`/WEB-INF/jsp`** folder.

So when you do this `return "homepage";` it will be converted to `/WEB-INF/jsp/homepage.jsp`, if your jsp is not present in this path you will get `404`.

Comment: added image with folder structure

Comment: Have you understood my answer? so according to your question if you place under WB-inf/jsp it's not working??

Comment: Yes I understood what you were trying to say,  but my jsp is present in the path /WEB-INF/jsp/  I am wondering if maybe the url I am typing in is wrong.  I have seen tried just about everything with .html and .jsp at the end in almost every combination it could possibly be.

Comment: Currently the mapping setup in the java class and the url pattern from the web.xml file being set to .html would make me think the url to trigger the  request would be (http://localhost:8080/projectHub/homepage.html)

Comment: check this answer,you will understand why..http://stackoverflow.com/a/39075538/4117061