# Swagger geneates urls not with suffix defined by url-pattern of servlet in the web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger

Here is my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/web-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but, when I try it out in Swagger-ui, it sends a request having a url without suffix '.do', surely 404  returns, how can I config it?

One way to fix it is to do some changes in the js of Swagger-ui, but it's not a good way.

Comment: go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073144/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-loginapp-in-dispatcherservlet-wit/39075538#39075538) and comments

Comment: why are you going for struts' .do pattern when you are using spring-mvc?