# error on loading login form - java spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

When i access the the base url, it should appear the login form first, but i recieve this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request and no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

So, i try to access my project like:
http://localhost:8080/project/

In web.xml i have this code:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

so, this means it redirects to login.jsp. and in that file ai have this code:

```
<form:form action="login/execute.html" id="signin-form_id" class="panel" method="post">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Error here
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form:input path="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username or email" />
    </div>
    <!-- / Username -->

    <div class="form-group signin-password">
        <form:input path="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <!-- / Password -->

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">
    </div>
    <!-- / .form-actions -->
</form:form>
```

and the error appear here:

```
<form:form action="login/execute.html" id="signin-form_id" class="panel" method="post">
```

so, i think the error occurs because i access directly the jsp and it should pass first through controller, and the controller to render the jsp
I have in a controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showLogin(){

    return new ModelAndView("login","command",new UserAdmin());

}
```

but is not working...

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

spring-servlet:

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.fabbydesign.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
</bean>
```

Comment: Show the complete `web.xml` file and the `dispatcher-servlet.XML` file

Comment: Is there any entry for `ContextLoaderListener` in `web.xml` ?

Comment: i have added to the question

Comment: @fabby change url request to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` it will work..`/` means any request that does not have a path info in it (urls without extension at the end), should be sent to the DispatcherServlet if you have anything then DispatcherServlet will not come into picture...http://stackoverflow.com/a/39075538/4117061

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason and solution:

> - Welcome file to work,you need change the URL pattern `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`..**`/`** means any request that does not have a path info in it.
> - With the URL pattern(`*.html`) `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` this will not work. You need to change either mapping to `value = "/.html"` or URL pattern.

More info about `<url-pattern>` is [here](http://docs.roguewave.com/hydraexpress/3.5.0/html/rwsfservletug/4-3.html).

Comment: this was the sollution but i had to remove:

Comment: but i had to remove this to work: <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</welcome-file>. Thanks all!