# Spring with REST

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

I am learning Spring framework. I have created a sample project with SpringMVC with REST + JSON. I can able to compile successfully but when i hit the rest url, the system says below message

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/rest/employee] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'.

Below is the **springmvc-servlet.xml**

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc.beans" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</bean>
```

And the **Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the **EmployeeController.java**

```
package com.springmvc.beans;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    public static final String GET_EMPLOYEE = "/rest/employee/{empId}";
    public static final String CREATE_EMPLOYEE = "/rest/employee/create/";
    public static final String DELETE_EMPLOYEE = "/rest/employee/delete/{empId}";
    public static final String GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES = "/rest/employee/";

    private Map<String, Employee> employeeData = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
    private Integer count = 1;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value=GET_EMPLOYEE)
    public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable ("empId") String empId){
        return employeeData.get(empId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value=CREATE_EMPLOYEE)
    public @ResponseBody void createEmployee(){
        employeeData.put(String.valueOf(count++), new Employee(String.valueOf(count++), "Batman"+Math.random(), "23"+Math.random(), "Andartica"+Math.random(), "dash2@gmail.com"+Math.random()));
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value=DELETE_EMPLOYEE)
    public @ResponseBody void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable ("empId") String empId){
        employeeData.remove(empId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value=GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeData;
    }


    {
        employeeData.put(String.valueOf(count), new Employee("1", "Mani", "31", "America", "Dash@gmail.com"));

    }
}
```

Finally the **Employee.java pojo**

```
package com.springmvc.beans;

/**
 * @author Mani
 *
 */
public class Employee {

    private String empId;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String address;
    private String email;

    public String getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(String empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Employee(String empId, String name, String age, String address, String email) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
    }



}
```

**Note :** My Spring version is 4.1 and I have added below jars in my classpath to convert output to JSON message

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Kindly help to solve this.

Thanks in Advance 
Manivannan

Comment: Which server you are using? Is it Tomcat?

Comment: yes **javaguy** i am using tomcat 7

Comment: What is your project name inside Tomcat webapps folder?

Comment: **javaguy** I am using eclipse IDE and running tomcat 7 inside eclipse. SO i cannot see my WAR file in webapps folder. My project name is **SpringMVC**

Comment: Then the issue is your project is not deployed into Tomcat, so you are not able to access the urls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No mapping found for HTTP request with URI \[/LoginApp/\] in DispatcherServlet with name 'java4s'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073144/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-loginapp-in-dispatcherservlet-wit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the code the endpoint is mapped to

```
public static final String GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES = "/rest/employee/";
```

where as the url being accessed is

```
/SpringMVC/rest/employee
```

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/rest/employee] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'.

Try making as below:

```
GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES = "/rest/employee";
```

Comment: HI @praveen, Thanks for your help. But even after i remove the "\" from REST path, It is not working. Same error message is displaying. :(

Comment: do other endpoints work ? or the issue is with all endpoints ?

Comment: I am sorry **Praveen** . It is working after removing the "\". Thank you so much for the help. If i want to configure the output either JSON/XML/TEXT then how do we do that here. Can you please suggest